# Algorithm to match one input file with given numbers of file

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, string-matching

I had an interview last week. I was stuck in one of the question in algorithm round. I answered that question, but the interviewer did not seem convinced. That's why I am sharing the same.

Please tell me any optimized method for this question, so that it will help me in future interviews.

**Question** :-

> There are 20 text files given, all files are ASCII text files, having
>   size less than 10^9 bytes.  There is one input also given, this is
>   also one ASCII file , say, input.txt.
>
> Our task is to strategically match the content of this input file with
>   given 20 files, and print the name of closest matching file. The
>   contents of input file might only match partially

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind reply.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer in this form. Are these files real text, or any printable ASCII, or base ASCII, or extended ASCII? Does the result have to be the best match, or is approximation enough?

Comment: I believe there is a system tool  for this particular purpose. `cmp` I believe is named. POSIX compliant SO.

Comment: @Kira Something tells me that isn't what the interviewer was hoping for!

Comment: @JBentley lol, just saying XD, sometimes reinventing available tools is not wise.

Comment: @Kira Except `cmp` does something completely different.

Comment: Btw. as a side note, it sounds to me as a very badly formulated indexing question.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be you are absolutely right

Comment: @Let_Me_Be This is a fairly common question for large data settings. It's really asking if you know about techniques for comparing large documents, for which there are some really sophisticated and interesting approaches. The file sizes tells you which part of the data fits in memory to restrict your available algorithm choices.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Result should be best match among all given 20 files. As this is algorithmic round, and he expected some algorithm from my side. So tell me any good approch.

Answer (score 3):

diff them and pass through wc -l, or implement [Levenshtein distance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in C++ treating each line as a single character (or any more appropriate unit condidering the subject domain)

Comment: +1, Very good answer, however, using an Edit distance algorithm its a bit difficult to implement (in my opinion).

Comment: @anonymous: down votes without constructive comments - not good

Answer (score 1):

You can create some kind of indexing (example: trie) to summarize the input file. Then you can check how many indices match across documents.

Eg. Create a trie for input file for length 10. For every string of length 10 (overlapping) in the text files check how many of them match in the trie.

Comment: Using trie would be inefficient as the size of file is large,instead using B+tree would be better option.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion for designing really capable, scalable systems for document similarity I'd suggest reading Chapter 3 of [Mining Massive Datasets](http://i.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html), which is freely available online. One approach presented there is to 'shingle' datasets by vectorizing word counts into sets, then hashing those word counts and comparing families of hashes results with Jaccard similarity to get a score between all documents. This can work on petabytes of files with high precision if done right. Explicit details with good diagrams can be read off Stanford's [CS246 Slides on Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs246/slides/03-lsh.pdf). Simpler approaches like word frequency counting are described in the book as well.